# Basic HTTP Authentication for REST Server on Drupal 7

Tags: rest, drupal, apple-push-notifications, basic-authentication

I feel like this might be answered already somewhere, but no one seems to have answered this question directly about Drupal and I'm wondering if that might be making all the difference.

I have setup a vanilla Drupal installation with just the necessary modules to use a REST server to handle Push Notifications. In testing the REST server with the CocoaRestClient (found here http://code.google.com/p/cocoa-rest-client/) I am encountering a problem with Basic HTTP Authentication (Authentication is failing).  I have tested with Session Authentication and that works perfectly. My username and password are most certainly correct.  The Services basic authentication module doesn't provide much in the way of setup, so what could I be doing wrong?

```
Modules being used:
Push Notifications
Services
Services basic authentication
REST Server
```

Drupal 7.22 minimal (vanilla install - no themes or any other fancy modules than the ones listed).

Comment: Did you make any progress on this? I'm stumbling with a similar situation.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  However, I have been able to get it to work unauthenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Basic auth enables you to GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE, to your endpoints using a Basic Auth Header. I am not sure if it will do anything for the /login end point. The authorization header should be made up of Basic followed by a based-64 encoded string of 'user:password' (not including the quotes). 
`Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==`

You can quickly test this using Postman or Fiddler.

Comment: Do you know how to send these in the header request? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724031/angularjs-with-drupal-8-rest-api < massive problem i'm having

Answer (score -1):

you need use the content access to restrict the access.  This will require users to provide a login and password.