# AngularJS - store basic authentication on login

Tags: angularjs, api, rest, drupal

I'm banging my head on a wall with this - I'm relatively new to working with APIs and have yet to do anything that requires authentication.

I'm stuck with sending a POST request to the API. The endpoint for creating a piece of content is:

```
/entity/node
```

I can send a successful POST request if I send the following:

```
headers: {
       "Authorization": "Basic YWRtaW46MTIzcXdl", //admin:123qwe
   },
```

The problem I am having is with Authorization. I'm specifying Basic and then an encoded string here, which is my admin login. So when hardcoded, I can post.

My question - when the user logs in correctly, I need the headers to be set so that all future post requests work. How can I do this in AngularJS?

I have tried passing a dynamically generated code:

```
"Authorization": "Basic " + auth,
```

where **auth** is a base64 encoded user:pass, but this does not work. My thinking is that this value needs to be stored somewhere for retrieval whenever a POST request is made. But how?

Comment: Have you found any information about that how Drupal's REST Api authenticates? I mean, OAuth, token, whatever?

Comment: I can't get OAuth installed. I'm trying to use basic authentication which is in core, but I don't want to have to pass a base64 string - there must be an answer to this.

Comment: Can you get data successfully from the api using another app? If so, I would check the network traffic with Fiddler to see what happens.

Comment: You can use [variable_set](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) to store the login value temporally (and be sure that when the user logs out delete it).

Comment: When you tried the dynamic version, what exactly went wrong? How did it fail? What was different between the two requests and/or the way they were constructed?

Answer (score 6):

Call this once you have a token:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(function (data, headersGetter) {
    if (authToken !== null) {
        var headers = headersGetter();
        angular.extend(headers, 'Authorization: basic ' + authToken);
    }

    return data;
});
```

EDIT:
Have not tested it, but it should be something like:

```
myApp.provider('authService', function() {

    var authToken = null;

    this.$get = ['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        return {
            configure: configure,
            setAuthToken: setAuthToken
        }
    };

    function configure() {
        $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(function (data, headersGetter) {
            if (authToken !== null) {
                var headers = headersGetter();
                angular.extend(headers, 'Authorization: basic ' + authToken);
            }

            return data;
        });
    }

    function setAuthToken(token) {
        authToken = token;
    }
});
```

and then inject `authService` to your app config and call `authService.configure()`

Comment: I tried to put this under .success() but it would appear I can only use httpProvider in config - can you explain how I would pass an auth token from the input inside the controller to a config item? Thanks

Comment: Edited my answer. Basically provider is available during config.

Answer (score 5):

In such cases what I usually have been doing is store any login token or such credentials(not passwords) in cookies and then access it via an angular service. Since angular services are singletons the value is retained throughout the app unless the page reloads which is where the cookie comes into play.
An example service that might look something like this

```
(function(){
  function Factory($resource, $q, $window, User, $cookie){
    var Resource = $resource(
                    // your resource config
                  ),
    res = Resource,
    proto = res.prototype;

    res.currentToken = null;
    res.currentUser = null;


    res.unsetAuthProperties = function() {
      delete $cookie.authToken;
      res.currentToken = null;
      res.currentUser = null;
    };

    // call this method after you retrieve the credentials
    res.setAuthProperties = function(response) {
      if(!response.id) {  
        res.unsetAuthProperties();
      } else {
        res.currentToken = {
          id: response.id,
          value: response.value
        };
      // set the current user
      res.currentUser = User.getInstance(response.jw_tokenable);
      // set the token in the cookie
      $cookie.authToken = res.currentToken.value;
    }
  };

  res.resolveCurrentUser = function () {
    var defered = $q.defer();
    // if the user is already signed in 
    // resolve the promise
    // if not do a manual resolve
    res.isSignedIn() ? defered.resolve() : resolve();
    // get the current user from the server
    // and resolve the promise
    function resolve () {
      res.current().$promise
      .then(function(response) { 
        res.setAuthProperties(response); 
      })
      .finally(function() { 
        res.isSignedIn() ? defered.resolve() : defered.reject(); 
      });
    };

    return defered.promise;
  };

  return res;

};
```

Once you have such a service ready use an angular interceptor to intercept the requests to which you want to add the auth headers to.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll upvote for now as I'm unsure if it will work for me. To be honest your example is way beyond my JS knowledge. I'll work through it and if it works I'll mark as accepted. Thanks for your time!

Comment: The main problem of this solution is that with BasicAuth you do not operate with login token but you have to always send user credentials to be authenticated.

Answer (score 5):

Use `angular-local-storage` to store your token in client's local browser when user get successful login.

[angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

```
$http.post('/token', data).success(function (response) {
    localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token,});
});
```

once you set token in local-storage, you are able to get it for that user.

like this : `localStorageService.get('authorizationData');`

Now use `authInterceptorService` to set header for each request

```
var _request = function (config) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
        if (authData) {
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Basic' + authData.token;
        }
        return config;
    }
```

here you get all details : [AngularJS Token Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, and Identity](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)

Answer (score 0):

angular js is simply javascript 
first you need to store your token in local storage 
after you retrieve your token then you will store it in local storage

```
 window.localStorage.setItem('auth_token', token);
```

then you will add it to    $httpProvider.interceptors  so every request will have your basic authorization

```
   myapp.factory("AuthI", function ($location, $q) {
    return {
      request: function (config) {

         config.headers = config.headers || {};
         if (window.localStorage.getItem('auth_token')) {
            config.headers.Authorization =  'basic ' + window.localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
         }
         return config;

     }
   };

});

myapp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
 $httpProvider.interceptors.push("AuthI");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am working on a project which deals with the same problem as yours.  As well, being new to Angular framework myself, I usually try to find a solution created by others and adapt it to my needs.

---

**angular-basicauth**

To deal with the basic authorization I have found an Angular module hosted here: https://github.com/iandotkelly/angular-basicauth.

It describes the configuration clearly, so I am not going to rewrite it all here. I think it serves all the purposes you would require it to. However, when using some already made solution you have to accept it's drawbacks. The one I really do not like is:

> Please note this module stores unencypted username & password in local-storage or cookies, so is susceptible to attack from code from the same domain

Since the module I have posted is based on MIT license you are free to grab the source code and play with it as you like. The solution is fairly simple and I believe modifying it is not a big deal. For instance, because I have found the cookie part unacceptable, I do not use cookies at all.

With this approach you have to modify it in a way you keep all the credentials stored in the angular service/factory (ie. `authService`) in a variable and read its' value when needed.

On the other hand, this modification brings a certain issue of manual reload of a page. In such case, since you reinitialize angular states, the user will be asked again to log in to your application. Unfortunately, there is no way (that I know of) that deals with basic-auth and lets you store the credentials safe. And since there is no session you could try to restore, you are basically choosing between unsafe local storage or in-memory variable (which seems safe enough for me).

---

**warning**

By using *basic-authentication* you are of course accepting all the limitations it has and obviously the biggest one would be the `base64` encoding of your credentials which is easily decipherable. Without using a secured protocol you are actually exposing the user data nearly in the same way as you would be by sending it as a plain text.